# Process more than 500 million rows to cube without performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cube, olap-cube

i have a huge database, for example :

My customer loads everyday 500 million records of data for sales in a buffer fact table called "Sales". I have to process this sales to my cube in append/update mode but this is destroying the performance even with 186 GB of RAM.

I've already tried to create indexes on the dimension tables, this help a little but not too much.

My customer said that they expect a 15% sales data increment every 6 months...

There is a smart way in order to load this data without to wait too many ours?

I'm using SQL-Server 2016.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the Sales data partitioned?

Comment: Question is too broad to answer, need more information. Example table structure, query you are using, index details, etc..

Comment: Are the 500 million rows new? Or are you processing all of your history? Is the cube partitioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt column store index feature of sql server 2016.
Columnstore indexes are the standard for storing and querying large data warehousing fact tables. This index uses column-based data storage and query processing to achieve gains up to 10 times the query performance in your data warehouse over traditional row-oriented storage. You can also achieve gains up to 10 times the data compression over the uncompressed data size. Beginning with SQL Server 2016 (13.x), columnstore indexes enable operational analytics: the ability to run performant real-time analytics on a transactional workload.

[You can have get more idea about this from microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a SAN to store your database.  You might want to look into some software like Condusiv V-locity to eliminate a lot of the I/O being sent to and received from the database engine.

I might suggest to create a separate database engine, to ship the transaction log over to a separate server and apply transaction logs to the DB every 15 minutes for you to create analytics without using live data.  Also the heavy writes to the production DB will not affect your ability to create complex query that locks the table or rows from time to time on your reporting server.

Comment: Consider including some links to `Condusiv` and `V-locity` to help out the asker.